# Passing additional parameter through Event Listener

Tags: javascript, textfield, addeventlistener

this code:

var messageLine = "this is a line of text";

```
myTextField.addEventListener('change', textHasBeenChanged, false);
```

calls this function:

```
function textHasBeenChanged(e) { var target = e.target; messageLine = target.value;}
```

Now I want to pass an additional piece of data... like a simple number 1. Like this:

```
myTextField.addEventListener('change', function(){textHasBeenChanged(theValueOfTheTextField, theNumber1);});
```

How can this be done? I'm still a programming newbie, so please keep your answer as close as possible to the syntax you see above.

Comment: you seem to be already doing this in your third code snippet. Can you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: In the first code snippet, nothing seems to be passed to the function, however when you reach the function, it seems to know that the "value" of the text field is "e". So when I try to pass an additional piece of data to the function, how does Javascript distinguish from the "value" of the text field, and some arbitrary parameter? I think the additional commentors have somewhat clarified this.Thank you.

Comment: e is the event object: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call/invoke the function inside of an anonymous function by passing the additional parameter. Also you can consider using [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `change` which is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is altered:

```js
var messageLine = "this is a line of text";
var myTextField = document.getElementById('myTextField');
myTextField.addEventListener('input', function(){textHasBeenChanged(event, 1)}, false);


function textHasBeenChanged(e, other) { 
  var target = e.target;
  messageLine = target.value;
  
  console.clear(); //clear the previous data in console
  console.log(messageLine);
  console.log(other);
}
```

```html
<input id="myTextField"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to take the even listener off afterward than you should be able to just pass the argument right to the function you're giving to the event listener

```
myTextField.addEventListener('change', textHasBeenChanged(1), false);
```

you dont have to pass `e` for the event because when provide a named function to an event listener `e` is already assumed to be the first argument